# How do I concatenate rows between cells of specified value?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use VBA to concatenate everything between two specified rows. What's the best way to go about this?

Basically I want to leave the lines where the third cell is "U" intact, and make the sixth cell of that row the concatenation of the rows below, until we run into another row that contains a "U" in the third cell. Then the process would repeat. The number of rows between the cells containing "U" is varied.

Pic is below

[image]

Comment: *trying to use VBA* - where is the code you've tried so far? please edit your question with your efforts thus far and where they are failing

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this should work (haven't tested it though):

```
Sub My_Amazing_Skills()
Dim l As Long, i As Long

l = 1
i = 1
Do Until i > Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row
    If Range("C" & l).Value = "U" Then
        i = i + 1
        Do Until Range("C" & i).Value = "U"
            Range("F" & l).Value = Range("F" & l).Value & " " & Range("C" & i).Value
            i = i + 1
        Loop
        Range("F" & l).Value = Trim(Range("F" & l).Value)
    End If
    l = i
Loop

MsgBox "Bow down to the great Jeremy!", vbInformation, "Your concatenating is done"

End Sub
```

I presume you know know where to copy this to?